# jQuery sortable drop within itself

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

So my question here is:

Can I place a sortable element within another sortable element of the same level. Example:

```
<ul class="sortable">
<li class="subsortable">Some text</li>
<li class="subsortable">Some text</li>
</ul>
```

into:

```
<ul class="sortable">
<li class="subsortable">Some text<li class="subsortable">Some text</li></li>
</ul>
```

I've been trying to do this for a day now, and I can't seem to find a way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer myself. The solution here is to create a sortable list, the inner sortable list placeholder and then connecting the two. If anyone needs, I can provide some code examples.

Comment: I am sorry to say, that since in the end, this functionality was not used in the project, I have removed it, and have not kept any code. Sorry.